# How to make different default accounts for Gmail and YouTube

Tags: gmail, youtube, google-account, account-management

I have two Google accounts. One is banned from YouTube but I can still use it for Gmail.
I have created another one for YouTube but every time I logon to YouTube with the new account and go to Gmail it shows new account's mail which is empty. I know I can switch to my old account by clicking on profile picture on upper right corner but I don't want to do this every time. J want to make two different default accounts for YouTube and Gmail.

tl/tr, **when I open Gmail it should open my first account and when I open YouTube it should open my second account**.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

1. <s>Use bookmarks for each service using /u/0 or /u/1 to use the default account or the second account.</s>
2. Some web browsers allow to have several users profiles. Use one profile for one service, and another profile for the other service
3. Use two different web browsers, i.e. Chrome and Firefox. Use one web browser for one service and the other for the other service

Comment: Thanks but i was doing exactly the way i described above but it was before formatting Windows. Now i can't do it. I am using Opera browser btw.

Comment: Have you tried alternatives 2 or 3?

Comment: I use 2 browsers but 3rd option is not suitable for me because i dont want to sign in that account with another browser. 2nd one which browser are you talking about and how can i do that?